# What the best scalability webserver to assets?

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, scalability, assets

I have two servers:

1. Application and database.
2. Assets (images).

In first I use Nginx (with Passenger and MongoDB). And in another, what the best option? Nginx, LightHTTP, Apache or other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the following link to [serve static files](https://serverfault.com/questions/249512/fastest-web-server-for-serving-static-content).

I have read and used apache for this purpose but apperantly based on the benchmarks, nginx and lightHTTP serves static files better.

Answer (score 0):

Here are Nginx and Lighty's performances, memory and CPU usage compared:

http://dsec.com/benchmark

And the KV store available above is much faster than MongoDB so you can use one single server to generate dynamic contents, query/feed/update a KV store, and serve images.